# How to resolve "module has no attribute 'entropy_decode_index' error in ubuntu for TFF?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I got "module '0b1a516c7ccf3157373118bcf0f434168745c8a4' has no attribute 'entropy_decode_index' error after a clean intall of tensorflow federated (TFF) on Ubuntu 22.04. System: AMD 6900HS, Nvidia3050ti. The first "import tensorflow_federated" line fails.

There is not even a single entry on google concerning this error message and I am shocked.

The detailed error message is:
File "/home/egosis/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_compression/python/ops/**init**.py", line 17, in

```
from tensorflow_compression.python.ops.gen_ops import *
```

AttributeError: module '0b1a516c7ccf3157373118bcf0f434168745c8a4' has no attribute 'entropy_decode_index'

Every answer is gladly appreciated.

I tried installing TFF v0.46.0, v0.45.0 and v0.44.0 of tff but it did not help.

Comment: You should always include a full traceback of this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please try again by installing the upgraded version of TensorFlow federated using code - `!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated` or can change the python version to 3.10. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.